# Using Firebase to store user input for products and record 'likes' and 'unlikes'

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to Using Firebase to store user input for products and record '**likes**' and '**unlikes**'.

I have created a '**ClothesListScreen**' and implemented the functionality for '**liking**' and '**unliking**' products.

that's my code.
**clothes_list_screen.dart**

```
class ClothesListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String prouductImage;
  final String prouductTitle;
  final String prouductPrice;

  const ClothesListScreen(
      {super.key,
      required this.prouductImage,
      required this.prouductTitle,
      required this.prouductPrice});

  @override
  State<ClothesListScreen> createState() => _ClothesListScreenState();
}

class _ClothesListScreenState extends State<ClothesListScreen> {

  String clotheImage = '';
  String clotheTitle = '';
  String clothePrice = '';

  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> gatData =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('clothes').snapshots();

  Future<void> addClothesToFirestore() async {
    final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    if (clotheImage != "" || clotheTitle != "" || clothePrice != "") {
      await firestore.collection('clothes').add({
        'image': clotheImage,
        'title': clotheTitle,
        'price': clothePrice,
        'like': isLikedList,
      });
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

  List<bool> isLikedList = List.filled(20, false);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    clotheImage = widget.prouductImage;
    clotheTitle = widget.prouductTitle;
    clothePrice = widget.prouductPrice;

    addClothesToFirestore();
  }
}
```

**clothes_model.dart**

```
class Clothes {
  String? image;
  String? title;
  String? price;
  bool? like;

  Clothes({this.image, this.title, this.price, this.like});

  Clothes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    image = json['image'];
    title = json['title'];
    price = json['price'];
    like = json['like'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['like'] = this.like;
    return data;
  }
}
```

**this is gridView widget.**

```
Widget gridViewList() {
    return ScrollConfiguration(
      behavior: const ScrollBehavior().copyWith(overscroll: false),
      child: Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
          child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: gatData,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final clothe = snapshot.data!.docs
                      .map((doc) =>
                          Clothes.fromJson(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
                      .toList();

                  return GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        mainAxisExtent: 230.h,
                        childAspectRatio: 5,
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 26.h),
                    itemCount: clothe.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final isLiked = isLikedList[index];
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Screen5(
                                  title: clothe[index].title.toString(),
                                  price: clothe[index].price.toString(),
                                  image: clothe[index].image.toString(),
                                ),
                              ));
                        },
                        child: Column(children: [
                          Stack(children: [
                            // Hear prouduct image , title, and price.

                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor: AppColor.whiteColor,
                                radius: 19.5,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      isLiked
                                          ? Icons.favorite
                                          : Icons.favorite_border,
                                      color: isLiked
                                          ? AppColor.blackColor
                                          : AppColor.grayColor,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        isLikedList[index] = !isLiked;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
                        ]),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return const AppLoader();
                }
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

plaese give the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If you step through this code line-by-line in a debugger, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do? Is there an error message?

Comment: No, there is no error massage, only I have to do Like & Unlikke, firabse na using to bus.

Comment: Can you clarify what the actual problem is? The question doesn't appear to be a question, just a statement about what it does. If you're having a problem with the code, please clarify the expected result and then what you're actually getting. Then provide details of your troubleshooting and what line is not working as expected.